# .NET assembly reference dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I've created a class library with a reference to two different assemblies, one taken directly from my local disk and other one taken directly from NuGet.

My library doesn't use directly the second assembly (the NuGet's one), but the first assembly depends on it.

When I build my library, in the `bin` folder I see three dlls, and everything seems correct.

Now: if I reference this class library from another class library and I build this last one, I cannot understand why the NuGet package is not automatically referenced, while the directly taken dll is.

I try to be clearer with a diagram:

- Assembly `LIB` --> depends on `A.dll` (taken from disk) and on `B.dll` (taken from NuGet)
- Assembly `Final` --> depends on assembly `LIB`

In final `bin` folder I see:

- Final.dll
- LIB.dll
- A.dll

but I cannot see B.dll

Why?

**EDIT 03/01/2015**

I tried adding a hard-dependency to B.dll in my LIB.dll by creating an instance of a class defined in B.dll. Now when I compile Final.dll, B.dll is brought to the bin folder.

So it doesn't seem that the problem is the difference between local dlls vs. NuGet's dlls, while it seems that the problem is in what I would call "weak-dependencies" vs. "hard-dependencies".

Comment: Answering the "why?" requires the detailed MSBuild trace.  You didn't provide one.  Start there first.

Comment: That's because B.dll is loaded from the local Nuget folder, which is separately created. This is also where Nuget binaries are updated if a newer version is available